# Change the font color of object names when displaying object names in the viewport

Tags: font

When I show object names in the Viewport, the font color by default is black.  How do I change the font color to something else?  I looked under Preferences with no luck.

Comment: How are object names shown, again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As weird as it sounds, object names in the viewport use the color settings from other elements.

For unselected objects, change the Wire color:

[image]

For selected objects, change the Object Selected and Active Object colors:

[image]

But of course it doesn't impact only the name: also the wire and outline, and on any object:

[image]

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.